# Remove links from my bibliography

Tags: bibtex

I am using this citation style in my thesis:

```
\usepackage[style=nature,citestyle=nature,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

and for some reason it prints urls (see figure). How do I remove them?

[image]

Comment: `style=nature,citestyle=nature,` is equivalent to the shorter `style=nature,`, because the `style` option just sets `bibstyle` and `citestyle` simultaneous to the same value. The software you are using to export your `.bib` file seems to LaTeX-escape characters in the URL field (the output shows `{\&}` where the real URL just has `&`): That should not happen. The `url` field is a verbatim-like field in `biblatex`, which means you do not have to escape most characters that would otherwise be special for TeX. Doing so regardless can cause issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you obviously could just delete the urls from your `.bib` file.

But the more convenient way is to disable them via `url=false`. This might only work with `biber` and not `bibtex`, which you are using. You have to try.

Pass this either as a package option or use:

```
\usepackage[...,url=false]{biblatex}
% or
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{url=false}
```

Comment: it worked beautifully for `biblatex`, thank you!!!